# Customise FileOpenPicker in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, fileopenpicker

I have a sub folder in downloads folder named 'StudentDetails'. It contains subfolders with student names.And each student name contains images related to that student.
By default, I want to open that StudentDetails folder (OnSuggestedStartLocation not reach the goal). And it should list all student name on left side. When user clicks on each student name corresponding files should show on right side. Is it possible on uwp?

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;

        foreach (string extension in FileExtensions.Video)
        {
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
        }

        file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as you know the `Filepicker` is a native windows component and the `UWP` utilizes it to fetch files as unlike `wpf` it doesn't have access to the local file system of windows. So in-case of a `wpf` I would have suggested you to simply create a control that does what the `filepicker` is doing but in `UWP` there is no way.

Please let me know if there is anything in the comments section

Comment: can I customize it in any other way? not using wpf. UWP.

Comment: @user2431727 I am afraid you can't. It's a system interface for picking files. The only thing you can customize it is the path at which it opens and the file extensions it allows you to picks

Comment: can I do it without a fileopenpicker? like take all sub folders name from main folder.and display it in a table.and then clicking on each of it will show its files on another table.like that?